# Displaying an <img> tag inside a div class

Tags: php, html, image

I have a problem here that deals with the displaying of a photo inside a variable within a div class.

Here's my code below and help me find solutions. Thanks

```
if($newimage){
    $url = 'http://www.client.jaobuilders.com/uploads/profile_picture/upload_photos/$newimage';
} else {
    $url = 'http://www.client.jaobuilders.com/images/blank_photo.jpg';
}

return '
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="avatar">
            '.$link_open.'
            <img src="'.$url.'" width="50px" height="50px"/>    
            '.$link_close.'
        </div>
```

`$newimage` is a variable and the value will depend on the user who logged in.
I really don't know what to do. Help me.

Comment: Everything looks fine from that.  Can you give some example output for $newimage and $url?

Comment: there's no photo shown on the page, i think the problem is that if the <img> tag is within the div class, the photo name should be specified not in a variable

Comment: It doesn't matter whether or not the IMG is inside a DIV.

Comment: Could you show us the produced page source?

Comment: Could be a problem with $link_open or $link_close too...

Answer (score 2):

You have a **problem with quotes** - some of them are lacking. Also **you did not close `<div>` tag**:

```
return '
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="avatar">
            '.$link_open.'
            <img src="'.$url.'" width="50px" height="50px"/>    
            '.$link_close.'
        </div>
    </div>';
```

I can only **hope this `return` statement is enclosed in some kind of function or method**. Or at least it is the only `return` statement in a file that has been properly included somewhere (like `$my_divs = include('some_file.php');`).